# Dropdown menu hover causes all other members of parent-child group to change color

Tags: css, plugins, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

I'm building [a site](http://concrete.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/index.php) using the Concrete5 CMS and am having some odd behavior with the menu plugin. When I hover over any parent menu item or its dropdown menu, any other element in that group becomes a dark gray. Using Chrome Developer tools and Firebug I haven't been able to find the source of this hover style, nor have I been able to locate it in the admin-editable custom stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Under hover styles in [this stylesheet](http://concrete.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/index.php/tools/blocks/jb_megamenu/customcss?bID=167&v=490fd1ad280dd2b3991f1bea26fc605c), there's a rule setting the text color to grey. I would bet it's that one.

/* Hover Styles */

.jbmm.custom ul.mega-menuh li.mega-hover a, .jbmm.custom ul.mega-menuh li a:hover {background-position: 100% -40px; **color: #333** !important; text-shadow: none;}
.jbmm.custom ul.mega-menuh li.mega-hover a .dc-mega-icon {background-position: 0 100%;}